# cuda fast approximate functions: what is the trade-off?

Tags: cuda

I was looking for sigmoid functions and sigmoid prime implementations for a sigmoid kernel, and I accidentally stumbled [upon a reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24543721/499699) to  in SO, which used `__fmul_rz` and some other CUDA function names.
So I googled them out of curiosity, and found that those are single precision functions [as shown here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE_g1beeb3ae544cfdde4a0a724ace025aed.html#g1beeb3ae544cfdde4a0a724ace025aed/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE_gc996beec34f94f6376d0674a6860e107.html#gc996beec34f94f6376d0674a6860e107)(Note: those are for 4.1).

The documentation says those are *fast approximations* so, intuition says that they skip on precision, in order to make computation faster?

Previously I had:

```
float x = 1.f / (1.f + exp ( -1.f * input ) );
return x * ( 1.f - x );
```

Whereas now, I have:

```
float s = __fdividef( 1.f, (1.f + __expf(-1.f*input)));
return x = s * (1.f - s);
```

Am I right to assume that the two above *may* have different results?

Comment: Current cuda docs can be found at http://docs.nvidia.com

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24085833/681865

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I right to assume that the two above may have different results?

Your assumption is correct. The fast math intrinsics trade performance for precision and handling of some special cases. It's up to the user to decide whether this is an acceptable tradeoff.

[**CUDA C Programming Guide, Appendix D.2. Intrinsic functions**](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions):

> Among these functions are the less accurate, but faster versions of some of the functions of Standard Functions .They have the same name prefixed with `__` (such as `__sinf(x)`). They are faster as they map to fewer native instructions. [...] In addition to reducing the accuracy of the affected functions, it may also cause some differences in special case handling.

The docs also provide a practical example of a difference:

> [...] for 2<sup>126</sup> < y < 2<sup>128</sup>, `__fdividef(x,y)` delivers a result of zero, whereas the `/` operator delivers the correct result to within the accuracy stated in Table 9. Also, for 2<sup>126</sup> < y < 2<sup>128</sup>, if x is infinity, `__fdividef(x,y)` delivers a `NaN` (as a result of multiplying infinity by zero), while the `/` operator returns infinity.

For `__expf(x)`, the maximum ULP error bound is stated to be `2 + floor(abs(1.16 * x))` while the IEEE-compliant `expf` has a maximum ULP error bound of 2.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was wondering where they explained the differences.