# CUDA intrinsic function advantage

Tags: cuda

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085833), is there any advantage of using the intrinsics (single, double or half) in the CUDA Math API. I understand some have faster (less accurate) versions such as `__fdivdef` and these can always be used with `-use_fast_math`, however what about the other functions. For example, why would one use `__fadd_rd(A,B)` instead of `A+B` or `__fmaf_rd(A,B,C)` instead of `A+B+C`? One reason I can think of is that one can choose the rounding method more conveniently - fine.

Also some  functions, for example `__fmul_rd` "will never be merged into a single multiply-add instruction" (according to the CUDA Math API documentation). Why would this be advantageous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The really short answer is that using something like `__fmul_rd` is never "advantageous", but sometimes use floating point instructions with clearly defined and fully predictable (or standardised) rounding and compilation behaviour is *required* to make calculations work correctly. [This](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html), for example.

The general rule is that if you don't understand why those floating point intrinsic functions exist, you shouldn't use them.

Comment: When not using the intrinsic function, is the default rounding mode for CUDA round-to-nearest-even as with GCC?

Answer (score 4):

Intrinsics give you finer control over exactly what operations your inner loop is going to do. If I call `__fmaf_rd`, I am virtually certain that the emitted PTX is going to have an `fma.rd` instruction without having to resort to writing inline assembly code.

I will therefore have no worries that the compiler might optimize the loop differently than I want<sup>*</sup>, or that there might be some subtlety of the standards I'm overlooking that requires the compiler to implement something more complicated than I thought I wrote.

Naturally, this is only a good motivation if I *really* know what I'm doing in this regard, but if I do, it's there for me to use. And being an intrinsic is superior to inline assembly, because the compiler actually understands the instruction.

<sup>*: You can't understand how frustrating it is when you *know* the best way to implement the loop, but the compiler keeps "optimizing" to something less efficient</sup>

Comment: Most often the reverse it true. You need to use intrinsic functions to *prevent* the compiler from performing optimisations like fusing multiply and add operations into FMAD and changing the rounding behaviour of a given floating point calculation.